# WordPress: Displaying whole template, not just the_content

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I've got a single page website with a front-page.php that shall include all my custom templates (each one is a static page).

```
<?php get_header();

$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$pages = get_pages($args);

foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
?>

<?php echo "$content" ?>

<?php
}
get_footer();
?>
```

With "the_content" it references only the content of my text in the backend, but not all my tags surrounding my the_content tag in the template itself, for example:

```
<?
/*
    Template Name: Features
*/

    the_post()
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<section>
    <? the_content() ?>
</section>

<?php endif; ?>
```

In this case, the surrounding tags **section** aren't selected and don't appear in the markup.

**What do I have to change in my front-page.php to select the whole template, not only its template?**

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the loop part of each page template in a separate template part and call the parts dynamically on your front page with [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part):

```
foreach ( $pages as $page_data ) {
    $template = get_post_meta( $page_data->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ); // get page template path
    $template = substr( $template, 0, -4 ); // chop off .php from the string
    get_template_part( 'loop', $template );
}
```

For a template 'Features' (filename `features.php`) it would look for `loop-features.php`, etc. Fallback will be `loop.php`.